# Fortran to C translation - mysterious division by one

Tags: c, fortran

I have encountered following code in FORTRAN77
(http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/SubirSarkar/bbn/fastbbn.f):

```
Update = 1.
do k=1,12
Update = Update + alpha(i,k,x,effN)*(R(k)-1.)/1.
enddo
Y = Y * Update
```

I am wondering about the division by 1.! Whats the reason?

I have translated to C as follows:

```
double Update = 1.;
for ( int k = 0; k < 12; ++k )
   Update += alpha(i+1, k+1, x, effN) * (R[k]-1.) /*/ 1.*/;   // CHECK!
Y *= Update;
```

Is that correct?

remark: due to different array indexing in C, there is a shift of +1 or -1 in the arrax index in comparison to the original code (I wanted to keep the same value as in the original code for the definition of the index and so for the index passed as arguments to function)

Thank you for your help!
Alain

Comment: Is it a cheesy way of forcing the result to a float?

Comment: oh as pointed out above, 1. is a double so it will return a double... assuming R is an int array of some type, it would convert to a double, but so would the assignment

Comment: R is a floating point array, alpha() also returns a floating point date

Answer (score 3):

The division by `1.` has no effect that I can discern.  Any type promotions that it might otherwise require are already required by the `-1.` in the dividend.

It is conceivable that on some specific platforms the division triggers some kind of desired behavior when the dividend has an exceptional value (i.e. an infinity or NaN), but that would be highly platform-specific.

It is also conceivable that the division is a holdover from some earlier version of the code where it actually had some effect.

Either way, your translation appears to be equivalent to the Fortran version, **EXCEPT** that nothing in what you presented justifies changing function `alpha()`'s first argument from `i` to `i+1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I know well that Fortran arrays are indexed from 1.  That has no direct bearing on function arguments.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, it may be that the translation *does* need `i+1`, but no such conclusion can be drawn from anything presented in the question.

Comment: Yes it has a justification but the reason cannot be recognised from the small piece of code presented here. Anyway, thank you for your answer!